# OpenCV/Python - Finding Outliers by Area of Bounding Box

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, object-detection

I have an object detection algorithm set up using TensorFlow, is there a way to remove the outliers in terms of the size of the boxes?

For example, I have 20 objects detected. Let's say 17 of them are around 50x50. But, there are a few bounding boxes that are 1x1 and one box that is 1000x1000. Obviously the 1x1 and 1000x1000 boxes are way too big and should be removed.

Comment: Here is an example: [jupyter notebook](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/kislayabhi/89b985e5b78a6f56029a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do that is to use the z_score.  The z_score will check how many std_devs does this number differs from the mean.

Example:

```
# coding: utf-8

import cv2
import numpy as np


bboxes = [(100,200), (120,210), (114, 195), (2,190), (104, 300), (111, 3), (110, 208), (114,205)]


def z_score(ys):
    mean_y = np.mean(ys)
    stdev_y = np.std(ys)
    z_scores = np.abs([(y - mean_y) / stdev_y for y in ys])
    return z_scores

thresh   = 1
outliers = [(t[0]>thresh or t[1]>thresh) for t in z_score(bboxes)]
```

This will print:
[False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False]

Comment: Can you offer any assistance with how to do so? I've tried looking around and I'm very confused on how to implement it

Comment: I was making a small code to help you with that and occurred to me that there was a simpler way.  I added the code above.  I hope it helps